# How does using wildcard in return type differ from defined generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class, which compiles fine

```
class MyClass<T> {
    MyClass<? extends Number> foo() {
        return new MyClass<Integer>();
    }
}
```

but when I change my return type to this

```
class MyClass<T> {
    <R extends Number> MyClass<R> foo() {
        return new MyClass<Integer>();
    }
}
```

I start getting error on my return statement, saying

`incompatible types: MyClass<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to MyClass<R>`

Comment: That's because `MyClass<Integer>` is not necessarily `MyClass<R>`. Should be `return new MyClasss<R>();` (or `return new MyClasss<>();`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because for second case

```
MyClass<Double> d = foo();
```

is valid call, but for first one is not.